# Sign of permutation

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations

Let $p,q \in \mathbb N$. How can I calculate the sign of the permutation
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & \dots & p & p+1 & \dots & p+q \\
q+1 & \dots & p+q & 1 & \dots & q
\end{pmatrix} \qquad ?
 $$

Comment: Hint: write down the two row form of the cycle $(1,2,...,n)$. Now deduce the two row form for its $m$th power

Comment: Yes @AndreasCaranti , perhaps it isn't...

Comment: @DonAntonio, ok, deleting comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sign of the permutation is just $(-1)^{\text{no. of inversions}},$ so it is enough to calculate the number of inversions. However, the permutation $\sigma=(q+1,q+2,\cdots,q+p,1,2,\cdots,q)$ does not have any inversion among the first $p$ or the last $q$ terms. And, any term from the first $p$ and another from the last $q$ form an inversion, because if $x\in[1,p],y\in[p+1,q],$ then $\sigma(x)\ge q+1>q\ge\sigma(y).$ So the number of inversions is just $pq.$ Therefore the sign of the permutation is
$$\text{sgn}(\sigma)=(-1)^{pq}.$$

Answer (score 0):

If you regard indices modulo $n = p+q$, this permutation $\sigma$ is simply the translation by $q$, as $x - p \equiv x + q \pmod{n}$. (Here we are choosing $1, 2, \dots, n$ as representatives of the residue classes modulo $n$.)

Now the translation $\tau$ by $1$ is even or odd according to whether $n$ is odd or even. And $\sigma = \tau^{q}$.
We obtain
$$
\operatorname{sgn}(\sigma) = (-1)^{(n-1)q}.
$$

In words,

- if $n$ is odd, then $\sigma$ is even,
- if $n$ is even, then $\sigma$ is even or odd according to whether $q$ (or equivalently $p$) is even or odd.

---

**Addendum** To obtain Potla's simpler formula, note that $(n-1)q = pq + q^{2} - q \equiv pq \pmod{2}$.